# Обработка HOOK в GetMsgProc

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Здравствуйте!
вот написал небольшое приложение с dll
dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    int kod;
    std::string symb;
    switch ( code )
    {
    case HC_ACTION:
        switch ( wParam )
        {
        case PM_NOREMOVE:
            kod = ((tagMSG*)lParam)->message;
            switch ( kod )
            {
            case WM_CHAR:
                symb += (TCHAR)wParam;
                MessageBox(NULL, symb.c_str(), "CHAR", NULL);
                break;
            default:
                return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
                break;
            }
        default:
            return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }

        break;
    default:
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

*exe cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "KeyLog_1.2.h"
#define WINAPI __stdcall

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
MSG msg;// текущий экземпляр
HOOKPROC hkprc;
HHOOK hhook;

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
//typedef LRESULT(CALLBACK *MSGPROC) (int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{       
    hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("G:\\Projects\\LOGG\\hook_dll_2\\Release\\hook_dll_2.dll");
    if ( hinstDLL == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, "DLL не загружена", "dll", NULL);  
    else MessageBox(NULL, "DLL загружена", "dll", NULL);
    hkprc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "_GetMsgProc@12");
    if (!hkprc )
    MessageBox(NULL, "функция GetMsgProc НЕ!!! найдена", "dll", NULL);      
    else MessageBox(NULL, "функция GetMsgProc подключена", "dll", NULL);    
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, hkprc, (HINSTANCE)hinstDLL,0);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, NULL, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Есть пару вопросов:

1. не обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку если открыть например блокнот... обрабатывает только если нажимать при развернутой VS.
2. не выводит символ....

Comment: switch в DllMain можете смело убрать, он все равно ничего не делает...